# Why would some characters be "expanded"?

Tags: passwords

I tried to sign up for an account on [nvidia.custhelp.com](http://nvidia.custhelp.com) and the password requirements stated 20 characters or less. I made a password 20 characters, numbers & symbols long, and got the following error message:

> The password you entered exceeds the maximum number of characters (20). Note that some characters are expanded upon submission which may cause the size limit to be exceeded.

1. Why would characters be expanded?
2. What would their expanded form be?

Comment: You should contact Nvidia Consumer Support for the answer to both these answers.  We don't have access to the necessary information to answer either of these questions.

Comment: I did ask them and they didn't know. I was just wondering if it might be due to a common programming issue.

Comment: My guess is they use [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), so all but 128 basic [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) characters are stored on 2 or more bytes. But it would also mean that they aren't handling these passwords correctly - they aren't using multibyte string-aware functions and possibly don't hash passwords properly (= they aren't stored in a secure way). Just a guess, though, we can't know for sure.

Comment: A terrible user experience: first they make you wonder about something that should be *their* problem, not yours; next their support is useless.

Comment: Another guess: this is on the web, and HTML expands some symbols, such as *space* [%20], You could test that by trying a 19-char password with and without spaces.

Comment: Because there are symbols that represent two or more characters.

Comment: @Fanatique Which ones?

Comment: ^You could look at the special characters you used in your password to narrow that question down a bit ;)